# What does the first "non-free" variable mean here when substituting in simple type theory?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, math-software, lambda-calculus, type-theory

See this screenshot of the book "Basic Simple Type Theory".  The infinite sequence they refer to is just a way to formalize the concept of having enough variables to work with no matter what.  In my case, for practical reasons, all my variables are single unicode chars.  I forsee for the next 100 years, that to be plenty of mathematical variables to work with.

So I'm in the process of implementing term substitution and I came across this ambiguity in the book:

[image]

What do they mean by the last line?  Do they mean the first non-free variable including any bound variables within $(N P)$?  Or do they mean the first "open, unused, available" variable in all of $(N P)$ including any abstractors $\lambda w$?

My guess is the latter, since $z$ is a dummy variable and of course this can't interfere with other variable useages.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you could without problem have multiple abstractors $\lambda z\cdot( ...\lambda z \cdot ...)$ - they just don't interact with each other. In that case, you can just use the first variable that's not appearing unbound in either $N$ or $P$. Though, if you got enough chars, option #2 of cause can never go wrong

Comment: Thanks @Sudix you are a gentlebeing and a scholar.